# Nodes do not append to the linked list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I've been implementing singly linked list in C++. However, I am struggling with the functions to insert a node after a specific node, and to delete a destinated node. I checked the node I parse into the functions and turn out the node don't even append to the linked list.

```
struct SNode {
string* element;
SNode *next; // Pointer to the next node

/* Creates a node. */
SNode(string* e, SNode* n)  {
   element = e;
  next = n;
}
string* getElement() { return element; }
void print() { cout << *element; }
};

class SList {
protected:      // data member
SNode* head;
long size;      // number of nodes in the list

public:
/* Default constructor that creates an empty list */
SList() {
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
}
// ... update and search methods would go here ...
long getSize() { return size; }
int isEmpty() { return size<=0; }

// add a new node to the beginning of the list
SNode* addFirst(string* s) {
    SNode* newNode = new SNode(s, head);
    head = newNode;
    size++;
    return newNode;
}

//remove the first node in the list
string* removeFirst() {
    if (head==NULL) return NULL;
    SNode* node = head;
    head = head->next;
    string* s = node->element;
    node->next = NULL;
    delete node->element;
    size--;
    return s;
}

// insert a new node after node n and store the string s there
void insertAfter (SNode n, string* s) {
    SNode* newNode = new SNode(s, n.next);
    n.print();                       //print out 2
    cout << endl;
    n.next = newNode;
    (n.next)->print();               //print out 6
    cout << endl;
    ((n.next)->next)->print();       //print out 1
    cout << endl;
    size++;
    SNode* iter = head;
    while(iter != NULL){
        if(iter == &n){
            cout << "ok" << endl;
        }
        iter = iter->next;
    }                                 //but not print out "ok"
    print();
    return;
}

// delete node n and return the string stored in n
string* insertAfter (SNode n) {
    SNode* iter = head;
    while(iter != NULL){
        if(iter->next == &n){
            break;
        }
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    iter->next = n.next;
    n.next = NULL;
    string* s = n.element;
    delete n.element;
    size--;
    return s;
}

//display the list's data in order from head to tail
void print() {
    SNode* iter = head;
    while (iter!=NULL) {
        // call SNode method to display iter's data
        iter->print();
        cout << endl;
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int isNode(SNode n){
    SNode* iter = head;
    while(iter != NULL){
        if(iter == &n){
            return 1;
        }
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
};

int main(void)
{
   SList* dl = new SList();
   string s1 = "1";
   SNode* p = dl->addFirst(&s1);
   dl->print();

   string s2 = "2";
   //dl->addFirst(&s2);
   SNode* p2 = dl->addFirst(&s2);
   cout << endl;
   dl->print();

   string s3 = "3";
   dl->addFirst(&s3);
   dl->print();

   string s4 = "4";
   dl->addFirst(&s4);
   dl->print();

   string s5 = "5";
   dl->addFirst(&s5);
   dl->print();

   dl->removeFirst();
   dl->print();
   dl->removeFirst();
   dl->print();

   cout << dl->isNode(*p2) << endl;            //still not print "ok"

   string s6 = "6";
   dl->insertAfter((*p2), &s6);
   dl->print();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you storeing pointers to `string` instead of copying the strings?

Comment: `iter->next == &n` in `insertAfter` will have too little chance to become `true`. I suggest you should use a debugger.

Comment: Why does a method named "insertAfter"() apparently deletes a node?

Comment: If you are using C++11, look at the [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) class, which is a single-linked list.  Otherwise, you should use [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (it is a double-linked list, but still very useful). This is the C++ way of managing linked lists. Unless you are taking a school course that forbids STL containers, you really should not implement this manually.

Comment: You really need to search the internet for "c++ single linked list" or use a debugger.

Comment: Please see the StackOverflow help center about [hot to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `SNode` objects *by value* to `insertAfter()` and `isNode()`, so the check for `== &n` will **never** be true.  You need to pass them *by pointer* instead.

Also, `p2` points at the second node in the list, but you are removing 2 nodes from the list before calling `insertAfter()` using the `p2` pointer that should now be invalid (had you implemented a valid remove function, which you didn't).

Try something more like this instead:

```
struct SNode {
    string element;
    SNode *next; // Pointer to the next node

    /* Creates a node. */
    SNode(string e, SNode *n) {
        element = e;
        next = n;
    }

    string getElement() { return element; }
    void print() { cout << element; }
};

class SList {
protected:      // data member
    SNode* head;
    long size;      // number of nodes in the list

public:
    /* Default constructor that creates an empty list */
    SList() {
        head = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    // ... update and search methods would go here ...
    long getSize() { return size; }
    int isEmpty() { return (size <= 0); }

    // add a new node to the beginning of the list
    SNode* addFirst(string s) {
        SNode* newNode = new SNode(s, head);
        head = newNode;
        size++;
        return newNode;
    }

    //remove the first node in the list
    string removeFirst() {
        if (head == NULL) return "";
        SNode* node = head;
        head = node->next;
        size--;
        string s = node->element;
        delete node;
        return s;
    }

    // insert a new node after node n and store the string s there
    void insertAfter (SNode *n, string s) {
        SNode* iter = head;
        while (iter != NULL) {
            if (iter == n) {
                break;
            }
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        if (iter == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        SNode* newNode = new SNode(s, iter->next);
        iter->next = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    // delete node n and return the string stored in n
    string removeNode (SNode *n) {
        SNode *iter = head;
        SNode *previous = NULL;
        while (iter != NULL) {
            if (iter == n) {
                break;
            }
            previous = iter;
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        if (iter == NULL) {
            return "";
        }
        if (previous != NULL) {
            previous->next = iter->next;
        }
        if (head == iter) {
            head = iter->next;
        }
        size--;
        string s = iter->element;
        delete iter;
        return s;
    }

    //display the list's data in order from head to tail
    void print() {
        SNode* iter = head;
        while (iter != NULL) {
            // call SNode method to display iter's data
            iter->print();
            cout << endl;
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    bool hasNode(SNode *n) {
        SNode* iter = head;
        while (iter != NULL) {
            if (iter == n) {
                return true;
            }
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
   SList* dl = new SList();
   SNode* p = dl->addFirst("1");
   dl->print();

   SNode* p2 = dl->addFirst("2");
   cout << endl;
   dl->print();

   dl->addFirst("3");
   dl->print();

   dl->addFirst("4");
   dl->print();

   dl->addFirst("5");
   dl->print();

   cout << dl->hasNode(p2) << endl;

   dl->insertAfter(p2, "6");
   dl->print();

   dl->removeFirst();
   dl->print();
   dl->removeFirst();
   dl->print();

   delete dl;

   return 0;
}
```

That being said, you really should use `std::list` (or `std::forward_list` in C++11) instead of implementing a list manually:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

//display the list's data in order from head to tail
void printString(const std::string &s) {
    std:::cout << s << std::endl;
}

void printList(const std::list<std::string> &v) {
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), &printString);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::list<std::string> dl;
    dl.push_front("1");
    printList(dl);

    dl.push_front("2");
    std::list<std::string>::iterator p2 = dl.begin();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    printList(dl);

    dl.push_front("3");
    printList(dl);

    dl.push_front("4");
    printList(dl);

    dl.push_front("5");
    printList(dl);

    dl.insert(p2+1, "6");
    printList(dl);

    dl.pop_front();
    printList(dl);
    dl.pop_front();
    printList(dl);

    return 0;
}
```